# How to disable "input methods" on SoftKeyBoard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I know this is not user friendly but i make a kiosk app, so my device will be inside a "container" which will hide the softButtons of the device. 
The problem is: if a user clicks on an "input option" he will never come back to the app, beacuse there is no `BackButton`.

I just want to know if it's possible to disable the button "input methods" on the default keyboard of my device (NEXUS 10) as you can see in the picture. If yes: how? Or do I need to write my own keyboard?

I also disabled all other keyboards on my device, but the button is still there.

[image]

However, on my nexus i don't have this button:

[image]

**UPDATE: 2013-11-07**

I noticed that on my nexus I also have the possibility to choose the "input options" settings -> longpress on the comma.

So I assume I have to write a softkeyboard on my own.

Comment: This is not a coding question.

Comment: Yes, your right. I also recognized that it's not possible to disable this button programmatically (-> I tried to get the `KeyEvent` of the `Keyboard`). I posted this question to be sure nothing to miss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem and decided to post this as answer, perhaps it will help others.

I have to write my own `Softkeyboard` that has no "Input methods" button. You can find a good sample at the [android samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) (note: [IME](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) is a feature since 4.0).

Because of Security reasons I can't select a Softkeyboard programmatically.
So I add an additionally setting where the user can choose a `Softkeyboard` with this code:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036435/switch-android-keyboard-profile-programmatically
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```