# How to integrate third party app apk in my android studio project?

Tags: javascript, java, android, apk

friends, i am making a messenger app in the android studio, I want to add Swift Braille Soft keyboard app APK in my app project.I want that when any person touch to type message just open Swift Braille Soft keyboard except default android keyboard.

Comment: There is. two possible ways. 1. Take the code of Swift Braille app and integrate it with your app. 2. You can send user to keyboard selection setting screen so that user can change the keyboard accept that it is already installed on system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking into integrating a 3rd party library called [SwiftBraille](https://github.com/MohammadAlBanna/Swift-Braille-Soft-keyboard). It may be what you are looking for.

And then to give the user a choice of keyboards to pick from, you can use:

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

You can take a look this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999658/1008011) if you are having trouble with switching keyboards.

Comment: No i do not want to give a choice i want to direct open this SwiftBraille keyboard.