# How to get this dialog to change the keyboard android programmatically

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How to open this dialog from my application to change the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch keyboard profile programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036435/switch-keyboard-profile-programmatically)

Comment: @ChrisStillwell Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) 
getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
```

Comment: How to get the text from input method picker?